# JS: OR operation with more than two operands?

Tags: javascript, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

This question is Javascript-based but applies to logical operation in general

take the code example

```
if (baseText[i] == "."){
    /*splice array*/;}  

if (baseText[i] == "!"){
    /*splice array*/}   

if (baseText[i] == "?"){
    /*splice array*/}
```

outputs what I want, but the following

```
  if (baseText[i] == "." || "!" || "?"){
           /*splice array*/}
```

should do the same, but doesn't. Forgive me, but my understanding of OR operation is that as long as one of the statements is true, the entire boolean value is `True` no matter how many operands I use. Am I getting it wrong in theory, or wrong in practice?

If it means anything I'm also iterating this "array.length" times

Answer (score 2):

```
if (baseText[i] == "." ||baseText[i] == "!" ||baseText[i] == "?"){
```